# HttpsURLConnection cast exception fromHttpsURLConnectionOldImpl

Tags: java, https, httprequest

Sometime on my application i get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl 
cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
```

It Persist until i restart my application.

A sample of my Java application tath make http request

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

    public class JavaApplication148 {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            URL url = new URL("https://my_url");
            HttpsURLConnection httpCon = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        }
    }
```

Making some tests I discovered that this problem only occurs in production ,where a ssl certificate is installed. It might depend on that ?

How can I fix ?

Comment: It will depend on what version of Java you're running in production. Must be an extremely old one.

Comment: I use java 6 on production and on development environment, where i making tests